# Movie about a boy who visits a old mansion and while there he is visited by a ghost. He flips between past and present as he solves a unsolved case

Tags: story-identification, movie

The story is the boy as the main character. There is a blind girl as well. It flips between present and past at the mansion.

There's also a fire where some guys hide money in a chimney.

Comment: This does sound a bit like "The Haunting of Hill House" but I don't recall anyone being blind.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds very much like *[From Time to Time](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1031241/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_2)*, a 2009 film adaptation of *[The Chimneys of Green Knowe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/377893.The_Chimneys_of_Green_Knowe)* by Lucy Boston.

The time travelling boy is called Tolly, who lives in a large manor house called Greene Knowe. He travels back to the 19th century and meets a blind girl named Susan, who lives in the same house.

From the [wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Time_to_Time_(film)):

> Susan leads him on an
> adventure that unlocks family secrets laid buried for generations.
> Exciting events include a terrible fire, a tale of stolen jewels, and
> threats of a servant being sold into a press gang.
>
> Although the lost treasure is found and Green Knowe is saved, Tolly's
> father is a casualty of the war. Mrs. Oldknow finally welcomes Tolly's
> mother into the family. Tolly is comforted when his father's ghost
> appears, assuring him everything will be all right.

The jewels belonged Susan's mother, a vain and silly woman, and were stolen by one of the house servants. Tolly finds that the servant hid them in the chimney of the old house, allowing him to find them in the present day and solve his family's financial troubles.